# Modeling single binary outcome (end-point only) with longitudinal covariates

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, panel-data

My dataset: I have a binary outcome variable (dispersed, not dispersed) that I would like to model using several explanatory variables. Some of the explanatory variables are single time point (e.g., origin, sex). However, because it takes several years for the outcome to occur, some of the explanatory variables are longitudinal (e.g., reproductive success, sea surface temperature). So, one individual might originate at site A, be female, experience average breeding success over 3 years (BS: 0.5, 0.3, 0.77), and average sea surface temperature over 3 years (SST: 13, 17.5, 20.1); ultimately this individual did not disperse in year 4.

I discussed this problem with a statistician, who explained that typically I might use linear mixed models (with individual as a random effect) to deal with the problem of repeated measures. However, because I don't have an outcome variable that corresponds to each longitudinal explanatory variable measure, this would not be informative. I'm currently planning to use logistic regression (binomial generalized linear model), but my understanding is that if I include each variable and time-point as separate parameters (e.g., SST_Year1, SST_Year2 ...) I violate the independence assumption. To make things more complicated, I have a fair bit of missing data; we don't see every individual in every year, so for some we only know breeding success in one year; or only in year 1 and year 3.

This led to my current plan to somehow summarize the longitudinal variables for each individual and include it as a single variable in the model (e.g. dispersal_decision ~ sex + origin + SST_Summary + BS_Summary). My questions are:

1. Does summarizing the longitudinal variables make sense given my
   situation?
2. Are there better/worse ways of summarizing the data to use as the variable? Averaging is probably the easiest option, but I expect that the difference between time points is more important; so perhaps I want to use variance or range?
3. Does the best method to summarize the longitudinal variable differ given different missing data scenarios? Is it bad to use variance or range if I have 3 years of data for one individual but only 1 year for another individual?
4. Is there a different method that I should investigate that addresses this problem explicitly?

I appreciate your help!